# SimpleWebRTC Signalling server - server.js not working

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, signalmaster

I try to do a [**simpleWebRTC**](http://simplewebrtc.com/) demo for screensharing.
For my signalling server, I used the server.js file at: https://github.com/andyet/signalmaster/blob/master/server.js

However, when I run the file on my Ubuntu as server, and browse to the port where I specified, I get the error message:

```
{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}
```

Without this server.js and using simpleWebRTC.com/latest.js as signalling  channel, I am able to do video chat, but not screenshare, since the signalling server for that is on HTTP.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Reverting to socket.io v0.9.x will solve it,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987640/socket-io-handshake-return-error-transport-unknown