# Receiving GET 400 when trying to implement socket.io communication. Node.js, ELB, Route 53, CloudFront, and s3

Tags: node.js, https, socket.io, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

Note** I was able to get things operational by taking cloudfront out of the picture for the server.com domain by just using route-53 and the elastic beanstalk environment. Still would be great to know why cloudfront was blocking this, but not an immediate concern for development **

I am serving a node.js static socket.io client form an s3 bucket using cloudfront and route 53. I am attempting to get this client to talk to a node.js web server using elastic beanstalk. The webserver is connected with amazon certificate manager generated ssl using a route 53 domain and cloudfront.

using an http client and directly connecting to the beanstalk environment I am seeing desired functionality. However, when I try to move to SSL/https with the client and server I am receiving:

```
(log from /var/log/nginx/error.log on elastic beanstalk instance)

"GET /socket.io/ HTTP/1.1" 400 51 "-" "Amazon CloudFront"
```

here is the client code that is running from the static s3 https domain:

```
import ioClient from "socket.io-client";

const ENDPOINT = "https://server.com";
export const socket = ioClient(ENDPOINT);
```

here is the server side. process.env.port is set to 8080, and I can verify the app is listening on 8080 through elastic beanstalk logs.

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const socket_io = require("socket.io");

const index = require("./routes/index");
const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socket_io(server);

const port = process.env.port || 4001;
server.listen(port, () => console.log(`http server listing on port ${port}`));
```

Inside the ALB I have an https listener set up on port 443 with Amazon Certificate Manager (ACM) ssl certification. The listener has a process that maps the 443 https to 8080 on http, from where I think ngnix should be acting as a reverse proxy to my socket.io listener on 8080

Listeners & Processors

[image: 443 being forwarded to 8080]

[image: https ACM SSL]

In the root of my node project folder I have a .ebextensions directory and inside that a file named 01_files.config with these contents:

```
files:
    "/etc/nginx/conf.d/websocketupgrade.conf" :
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
             proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
             proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
             proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
             proxy_http_version 1.1;
             proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

From the comments in this post : [socket.io handshake return error "Transport unknown"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987640/socket-io-handshake-return-error-transport-unknown) I found the following socket.io error codes

```
engine.io message type:

open =0
close =1
ping =2
pong =3
message =4
upgrade =5
noop =6
socket.io message type:

connect = 0
disconnect = 1
event = 2
ack = 3
error = 4
binary_event = 5
binary_ack = 6
```

so, 400 51 could possibly mean "Bad request, upgrade-disconnect."

Here is the response body :
`{"code":0,"message":"Transport unknown"}`

And here is the error on the client app in browser:

`polling-xhr.js:268 GET https://server.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NIgQkyr 400`

which looks like a failed polling request on the xhr transport layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received this solution from AWS support:

> I have discussed your case with a CloudFront (CF) expert and I have
> some information for you.
>
> After going through the CF setup with my colleague, we noticed that CF
> is not forwarding the HOST header to Elastic Beanstalk (EB). This
> means if the connection between CF and EB is established over HTTPS,
> it will fail. To fix this, we had to take a look at the CF policies.
> We noticed that you are making use of Cache Policies. In this policy
> there is a setting for Headers. Here I would recommend that you
> specify the HOST setting. This way, it secures the HTTPS connection
> against the Origins certificated.
>
> If that does not work, there is something else I could suggest. The
> error you were seeing (GET /socket.io/ HTTP/1.1" 400 51 "-" "Amazon
> CloudFront" "(redacted IP, redacted IP") should have returned an
> "X-Amz-Cf-Id" ID along with a value (something like "X-Amz-Cf-Id:
> jkahDAKJSHDAjhAKSJDHasd=="). Since it did not, I suspect something may
> have gone wrong with the websocket request parameters. For this I
> would recommend taking a look at our documentation and ensure that the
> correct request parameters required for CloudFront are being used. You
> can find a link to that documentation here: [1].
>
> If all else fails, I would recommend making a request to your CF and
> record the key-value pair that is returned in the response header from
> CF. It should look something like "X-Amz-Cf-Id:
> jkahDAKJSHDAjhAKSJDHasd==" (the same ID and value I mentioned
> earlier). This value allows us as support engineers to pull the
> internal logs for CF using our tooling. This value will need to be
> recorded at the time of the request. Once you have this key-value
> pair, you can then open a support ticket with the CloudFront team,
> provide them with the error details as well as the key-value pair, and
> a CF engineer would be more than happy to assist you. Additionally,
> you could even reference this case (case ID = 7399701121) on the new
> case so that the engineer assisting you can have some more context.
>
> To sum up, my first recommendation is that you forward the host
> header. Second is to use the request parameters required for
> CloudFront. And last, if you encounter another error after that,
> record the value from the HTTP response given by CloudFront for the
> error. Since I am not a CloudFront expert, I would suggest opening a
> new CloudFront case and providing that key-value pair in the message.
>
> I hope you find this information useful. If you have any more
> questions or concerns, please feel free to reach out.

Comment: Hi Lucas, we are having a similar issue. 
we have our socket io in ec2 machine and s3 has our app which is trying to establish a connection. 
could you have a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205150/trying-to-connect-to-socket-io-punning-on-node-on-ec2-machine-from-react-app-hos